# Splash screen does not appear

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I wrote the manifest file to show it.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: app.App
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.png
```

and when I wrote the below code and ran the jar file,

```
final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();

if (splash == null) {
    System.out.println("null");
    return;
}

Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();

if (g == null) {
    System.out.println("null");
    return;
}
```

I always get "`null`" message. What am I missing?

Comment: "*What am I missing?*" > An explanation of which line threw the NPE.

Comment: Did you check that the image is contained in the jar and in the correct location? Did you try using the `-splash:<path_to_image>` option on the command line in order to check whether the code itself would work?

Comment: Obviously ``SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()`` does not return a valid instance, but ``null``. What does that method do, did you write it yourself? Provide more information, please (e.g. code of SplashScreen class or library you are using). The NPE is thrown when you call ``splash.createGraphics()``, I suppose?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  One typical problem with trying to manipulate the splash is that it is done too late.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check if MANIFEST.MF file inside generated jar contains SplashScreen-Image entry, if not try to correct your existing manifest file inside your project and don't forget to add end of line to it.

From [Oracle Modifying a Manifest File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) : **Warning: The text file from which you are creating the manifest must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson a comment is also an answer so all is answer, so i prefer answer with bigger space and clear text.