# splash screen not appearing in android after trying many solutions

Tags: android, android-activity

I am very new to android and I am trying to implement a splash screen by following a tutorial from a website.

I did everything that was written there but When I run my app, the splash screen does not appear.

**I took reference from many questions on StackOverflow but that does not seem to work**

[Splash screen does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567356/splash-screen-does-not-appear)

**Below is my "activity_splash" file, located at "res->layout->activity_splash.xml"**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image_offline" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="www.androidhive.info" />
```

**Below is my "SplashScreen.java" file located beside MainActivity.java file**

```
// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

*

*Below is my "AndroidManifest.xml" file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.gold.webview.codecanyon.com.bakairy.WebViewApp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="android.gold.webview.codecanyon.com.bakairy.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/deeplinking">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://bakairy.boehub.com/link=” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="https://bakairy.boehub.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/link="
                />

        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
</application>
```

Comment: `postDelayed` means that `run()` is only triggered after a period of time. In your code, it means that your `SplashActivity` only starts after 3 seconds

Comment: you should set the _intent_filter_ of .MainActivity to .SplashScreen in _AndroidManifest_. That should do the work.

Comment: thanks @dazed'n'confused. It worked

Answer (score 3):

Your Splash Screen not appearing because you have `MainActivity` as the launcher activity in `manifest`

Change your `manifest` code:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> bro to start activity first you have to make it launch first, I am modifying your code, use it instead. replace your manifest code for the splash activity. and remove the intent filter from main activity

```
  <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" >
```

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set intent-filter in splash screen only..
like this..

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

MainActivity does not need the intent-filter you have to remove it.

Comment: thanks for answering @manan. As a complete beginner in android, I am unable to understand where to update. Can you please help me out with this?